# Removing the bracket and empty string

Tags: java

The end result of the code is to be able to parse the string array to integer array but as you can see I get an exception. I tried to split the [ and ] signs but when I call the first (0) element splited_game_result[0] of the array, it's returns nothing. What is the solution here? I tried using trim method.

```
    String[] ca_po_pe = {"4:7","PAUSE","2:0","1:3 PINE","PAUSE","CANCEL","2:4","0:5 PINE","PAUSE","CANCEL"}; 

    String canc_postp_pen_games = ""; 

   boolean confirming = true;

   for(String looped_games : ca_po_pe) { 

   if(confirming) { canc_postp_pen_games+=looped_games; confirming=false; } 

    else { canc_postp_pen_games+=", "+looped_games; } }

   System.out.println("LOOPED FINAL RESULT GAMES TO INSERT COMMAS: " + "\n" + canc_postp_pen_games + "\n"); 

    String[] fin_games_res = canc_postp_pen_games.split("[,]");

    ArrayList<String> arraylist= new ArrayList<String>();

    Collections.addAll(arraylist, fin_games_res);

    for (String str: arraylist) {     
      }

    System.out.println("ELEMENTS ADDED TO ARRAYLIST: " + arraylist + "\n");

int noItems = arraylist.size(); 

for (int i = 0; i < noItems; i++) { 

String currItem = arraylist.get(i); 

if (currItem.contains("PAUSE")) { 
arraylist.add(new String("400"));
noItems++; } 

if (currItem.contains("CANCEL")) { 
arraylist.add(new String("300")); 
noItems++; } 

if (currItem.contains(" PINE")) { 
arraylist.add(new String("500")); 
noItems++; }
    }

   System.out.println("ELEMENTS BEFORE REMOVAL: " + "\n" + arraylist + "\n");

 Iterator<String> iter_getting = arraylist.iterator(); 

 while(iter_getting.hasNext()) { 

 if(iter_getting.next().contains("PAUSE")){ 
   iter_getting.remove(); }}

   Iterator<String> iter_getting1 = arraylist.iterator(); 

   while(iter_getting1.hasNext()) { 

 if(iter_getting1.next().contains("CANCEL")){ 
   iter_getting1.remove(); }}

   Iterator<String> iter_getting2 = arraylist.iterator(); 

   while(iter_getting2.hasNext()) { 

 if(iter_getting2.next().contains(" PINE")){ 
   iter_getting2.remove(); }}

  System.out.println("ELEMENTS AFTER REMOVAL: " + "\n" + arraylist);

    System.out.println("ELEMENT ON INDEX 3 BEFORE CONVERTION TO ARRAY: " + "\n" + arraylist.get(3));

    String convert = arraylist.toString();

    System.out.println("CONVERTED STRING: " + convert);

    String[]splited_game_result = convert.trim().split("[\\[:,\\]]");

    System.out.println(" AFTER SPLITING TO ARRAY: " + "\n" + splited_game_result[0]);

    Integer[] final_result = new Integer[splited_game_result.length];

    int g = 0; 

    for(String fsgr : splited_game_result)
```

{ final_result[g] = Integer.parseInt(fsgr); g++;}

```
    System.out.println("INTEGER ELEMENT ON INDEX 0: " + "\n" + final_result[1]);
```

Comment: You should consider making your code readable. Noone is going to read through this.

Comment: Just say what is the input and what should be the output. The code is impossible to follow :/

Comment: I attempted to copy your code and hand-format it.  I gave up.

Comment: I formatted the code but I don't have an hour to determine what you're trying to do. By the way, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everybody who wonders, exception is raised in the very end of the source. It says `NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`. See source below:

```
for(String fsgr : splited_game_result)
{ final_result[g] = Integer.parseInt(fsgr); g++;}
```

The reason is in the regular expession author used to split the array:

```
String[]splited_game_result = convert.trim().split("[\\[:,\\]]");
```

It produces the following array of strings:
`["", "4", "7", "  2", "0", "  2", "4", " 400", " 500", " 400", " 300", " 500", " 400", " 300"]`

Issue is that `Integer.parseInt` requires [string that contain parsable integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Possible workaround is to add `if condition` to ensure your `fsgr` is not an empty string and doesn't contain whitespaces:

```
for(String fsgr : splited_game_result) {

    String fsgrTrim = fsgr.trim();

    if (!fsgrTrim.isEmpty()) {
        final_result[g] = Integer.parseInt(fsgrTrim);
        g++;
    }
}
```

Or to add try-catch clause:

```
for(String fsgr : splited_game_result) {
    try {
        final_result[g] = Integer.parseInt(fsgr);
        g++;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what you're trying to do, but here is your exception. You are parsing an empty string and trying to parse a space before the number. Put comments in for your logic.

```
for (String fsgr : splited_game_result) {
    try {
        final_result[g] = Integer.parseInt(fsgr);
        g++;
    } catch(Exception e2) {
       System.out.println("Exception = ["+ fsgr + "]");
    }
}
```

Output (in middle of put. Use first and last printlns as location)

```
CONVERTED STRING: [4:7,  2:0,  2:4, 400, 500, 400, 300, 500, 400, 300]
AFTER SPLITING TO ARRAY: 

Exception = []
Exception = [  2]
Exception = [  2]
Exception = [ 400]
Exception = [ 500]
Exception = [ 400]
Exception = [ 300]
Exception = [ 500]
Exception = [ 400]
Exception = [ 300]
INTEGER ELEMENT ON INDEX 0: 
7
```